# PHP Carbon nth days of the month

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

January 19, 2018 is the third Friday of the month.

I want the number 3 denoting that this is the third Friday.  Can Carbon do this?

Further, I'll then be using that to check to see if another date is before or after the third Friday of another month.   For instance, is February 17, 2018 before or after the third Friday in February?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon is a layer on top of the PHP class [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), which is very powerful as it supports many formats that are outlined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), specifically you're looking for the [Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

`Third friday of february` is a valid Relative Format, therefore, you can do something like this:

```
Carbon::parse('February 17th') > Carbon::parse('third friday of february');
```

And that will produce `true`, whereas:

```
Carbon::parse('February 15th') > Carbon::parse('third friday of february');
```

Will produce `false`.

You need to be mindful that formatting is very important when constructing this way, for example, `third friday in february` is not valid.

---

I don't believe that there's any functionality within the DateTime class that would allow for the first part in a single DateTime format, however, you can use something like this:

1. Determine the day of the provided date
2. Find the first of that day in the month
3. Compare (number of days / 7) between your date and the first day

e.g:

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::parse('January 18 2018');

$firstDay = Carbon\Carbon::parse("first {$date->format('l')} of {$date->format('F')}");
$nth = $firstDay->diffInDays($date) / 7 + 1;

echo "{$date->format('Y-m-d')} is the #{$nth} {$date->format('l')} in this month";
```

Comment: Wow I didn't realize those Relative Formats existed. Very good to know.

Comment: This is a great answer for the second half of the question.  What I don't know if how to get the string "third Friday" from January 19, 2018.

Comment: @MichaelArrison Sorry about that, I've updated my answer to include an example of how you could do the first part of your question with this knowledge. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it can.

Edit: Ignore this

I don't think Carbon can do exactly what you're asking directly, but doing some calculations using the builtin getters I'm sure you could achieve this quiet easily.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

Start with parsing the date:

```
$dt = Carbon::parse('2018-19-1 23:26:11.123789');
```

Then use `weekOfMonth`, `dayOfMonth`, `dayOfWeek`, etc.